# Сортировать Словарь в python

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь, типа такого: `{"player1": 2340, "player2": 51609, "player3": 8781}`. Мне нужно составить топ игроков (чем больше очков, тем лучше), и чтобы словарь выглядел так: `{"player2": 51609, "player3": 8781, "player1": 3240}`. Я не особо опытный и прошу помочь, до самого что-то не допирает.

Comment: Словарь это неупорядоченное множество ключей с ассоциированными с ними значениями. Так что `словарь` и `сортировать` это несочетаемые слова. Вам нужна другая структура (например, список словарей).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
d = {"player1": 2340, "player2": 51609, "player3": 8781}

list_d = list(d.items())
list_d.sort(key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)

print(list_d)
# [('player2', 51609), ('player3', 8781), ('player1', 2340)]

d_new = {i[0]: i[1] for i in list_d }
print(d_new)
# {'player2': 51609, 'player3': 8781, 'player1': 2340}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не подскажите, а как сделать что-то типо этого: [ {'player2': 51609}, {'player3': 8781}, {'player1': 2340} ]. Чтобы был массив.

Comment: @Григорий   `d_new = [ {i[0]: i[1]} for i in list_d ]`

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Это неверный ответ. Порядок ключей в словаре не гарантируется. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: @КириллМалышев, начиная с Python 3.6 порядок, в котором добавлялись элементы в словарь, сохраняется: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/3350428.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov И там же сказано, что это деталь **реализации**, а не языка, и на неё не стоит полагаться.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, сойдемся на том, что, начиная с 3.7, это уже является частью спецификации языка и сохранение порядка обязательно :) Так же, ничто не мешает использовать класс [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: @AndreiOdegov, такая информация должна указываться в ответе.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, согласен. Но и автор вопроса в таком случае должен предоставить достаточно информации для того, что бы получить наиболее оптимальный ответ.